# Why are there escape sequences in my *Warnings* buffer and how to get rid of them?

Tags: spacemacs

I got this warning while trying to activate the python layer in spacemacs. However, the escape sequences are not unique to this situation; they are usually present whenever there are warnings in the **Warnings** buffer. Why are they there and how do I get rid of them?

---

OS: macOS 10.13

Emacs Version: 25.3.1

Spacemacs Version: 0.200.9

Shell: zsh (using oh-my-zsh)

.spacemacs: https://pastebin.com/vKVUxFad

---

**Warnings** Buffer:

```
Error (use-package): python :init: Invalid version syntax: ‘^[]4;0;rgb:1d/1f/21^[\^[]4;1;rgb:cc/66/66^[^\[]4;2;rgb:b5/bd/68^[\^[]4;3;rgb:f0/c6/74^[\^[]4;4;rgb:81/a2/be^[\^[]4;5;rgb:b2/94/bb^[\^[]4;6;rgb:8a/be/b7^[\^[]4;7;rgb:c5/c8/c6^[\^[]4;8;rgb:96/98/96^[\^[]4;9;rgb:cc/66/66^[\^[]4;10;rgb:b5/bd/68^[\^[]4;11;rgb:f0/c6/74^[\^[]4;12;rgb:81/a2/be^[\^[]4;13;rgb:b2/94/bb^[\^[]4;14;rgb:8a/be/b7^[\^[]4;15;rgb:ff/ff/ff^[\^[]4;16;rgb:de/93/5f^[\^[]4;17;rgb:a3/68/5a^[\^[]4;18;rgb:28/2a/2e^[\^[]4;19;rgb:37/3b/41^[\^[]4;20;rgb:b4/b7/b4^[\^[]4;21;rgb:e0/e0/e0^[\^[]10;rgb:c5/c8/c6^[\^[]11;rgb:1d/1f/21^[\^[]12;rgb:c5/c8/c6^[\6.2.1’ (must start with a number)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that zsh is always invoked  with full-color ANSI escape sequence „fontification”.  This may look nice on a terminal, but plain text modes like the *Warnings* buffer cannot display those colors.  Since I don't use oh-my-zsh, I cannot tell the exact way to remove this setting, but the invocation of zsh has to include the parameter `--colors=never` or `--colors=auto`.   You should do `M-x customize-group oh-my-zsh` and find an entry like „zsh invocation”.  Alternately, you can generally set zsh to use colors only where appropriate (in its own rc file).